# Strong Law of Large Numbers (Klenke's proof)

Tags: probability-theory

This is a part of the proof of the SLLN in *Achim Klenke: »Probability Theory — A Comprehensive Course«* (page 113).

[image]

Now, what does "$\mathbb{1}_{\{x < n\}}$" (sorry, can't typeset this properly) mean in this context? What kind of set shall $\{x < n\}$ be?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think, it simply abbreviates the set notation $\{x<n\}:=\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\,x<n\}$, i.e. practically the integral goes only until $n$ instead of $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1_{\{x<n\}} = 1_{(-\infty,n)}(x)$$